# Simple Android - How to show different data when button is pressed

Tags: android

I am working on a simple android application. I have a Quiz Session. And a database that has the Categories, Question, and Options. On my activity_main, I want to dynamically show questions and the corresponding options. So far, the questions are dynamic (if I press tab 3, I see the question text for #3), however, I do not understand how to change the option. I am currently putting dummy values in by adding buttons to the linear layout. Please help me!

```
public class QuizSessionActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections.
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
QuestionPagesAdapter mQuestionPagerAdapter;
QuizDB db;
//static Question curr;
/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;
String category;
static List<Question> questions;
static int pos;
/**
 * Create the activity. Sets up an {@link android.app.ActionBar} with tabs, and then configures the
 * {@link ViewPager} contained inside R.layout.activity_main.
 *
 * <p>A {@link QuestionPagesAdapter} will be instantiated to hold the different pages of
 * fragments that are to be displayed. A
 * {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener} will also be configured
 * to receive callbacks when the user swipes between pages in the ViewPager.
 *
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    category = intent.getStringExtra("cat");
    // !!!!! Put real questions here
    // Set up the action bar. The navigation mode is set to NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS, which will
    // cause the ActionBar to render a set of tabs. Note that these tabs are *not* rendered
    // by the ViewPager; additional logic is lower in this file to synchronize the ViewPager
    // state with the tab state. (See mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener() and onTabSelected().)
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.
    mQuestionPagerAdapter = new QuestionPagesAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mQuestionPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab. We can also use
    // ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mQuestionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter. Also
        // specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // callback (listener) for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mQuestionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_finish:
            // TODO: Handle finish here

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Update {@link ViewPager} after a tab has been selected in the ActionBar.
 *
 * @param tab Tab that was selected.
 * @param fragmentTransaction A {@link android.app.FragmentTransaction} for queuing fragment operations to
 *                            execute once this method returns. This FragmentTransaction does
 *                            not support being added to the back stack.
 */
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, tell the ViewPager to switch to the corresponding page.
    pos = tab.getPosition();
    Fragment fragment = new QuestionSectionFragment();
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

/**
 * Unused. Required for {@link android.app.ActionBar.TabListener}.
 */
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * Unused. Required for {@link android.app.ActionBar.TabListener}.
 */
@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages. This provides the data for the {@link ViewPager}.
 */
public class QuestionPagesAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public QuestionPagesAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Get fragment corresponding to a specific position. This will be used to populate the
     * contents of the {@link ViewPager}.
     *
     * @param position Position to fetch fragment for.
     * @return Fragment for specified position.
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a QuestionSectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new QuestionSectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        //  Put real questions here
        db = new QuizDB(getApplicationContext());
        questions = db.getCategoryQuestions(category);

        args.putString(QuestionSectionFragment.ARG_QUESTION_NUMBER, ""+(position + 1));
        args.putString(QuestionSectionFragment.ARG_QUESTION_TEXT, questions.get(position).getBodyText());
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        //curr = questions.get(pos);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * Get number of pages the {@link ViewPager} should render.
     *
     * @return Number of fragments to be rendered as pages.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 10 total pages.
        return 10;
    }

    /**
     * Get title for each of the pages. This will be displayed on each of the tabs.
     *
     * @param position Page to fetch title for.
     * @return Title for specified page.
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return new Integer(position + 1).toString();
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 * This would be replaced with your application's content.
 */
public static class QuestionSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_QUESTION_NUMBER = "question_number";
    public static final String ARG_QUESTION_TEXT = "question_text";

    public QuestionSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView questionTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        questionTextView.setText(args.getString(ARG_QUESTION_TEXT));
        LinearLayout answerBox = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.question_box);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            Button option = new Button(getActivity());
            //  real answer options here

            option.setText(questions.get(pos).getOptions().get(i - 1).getOptionText());
            option.setContentDescription(String.format("q%s_o%s", args.getString(ARG_QUESTION_NUMBER), i));
            answerBox.addView(option);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
    /*
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View rootView = v;
        TextView questionTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        questionTextView.setText(args.getString(ARG_QUESTION_TEXT));
        LinearLayout answerBox = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.question_box);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            Button option = new Button(getActivity());
            //  real answer options here

            option.setText(questions.get(pos).getOptions().get(i - 1).getOptionText());
            option.setContentDescription(String.format("q%s_o%s", args.getString(ARG_QUESTION_NUMBER), i));
            answerBox.addView(option);
        }
    }*/

}
```